# jQuery/bgStretcher fading to black instead of between images

Tags: jquery, fade

http://lakefrontmotorlodge.co.nz/new/

I am trying to get the background to fade smoothly, but it fades to black before fading in the image. I know there can be an issue with images loading in time, but even when all the images are loaded trying to cycle through it still fades to black before the next image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The .css had been tampered with, restored original and now it works.